# Why does $2^{10}\equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ and $2^{30} \equiv 1 \pmod {31}$ "easily" imply $2^{341}-2$ is divisible by both 11 and 31?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Background: This is from a proof that 341 is the lowest pseudoprime, meaning it passes the base test $a^n\equiv a \pmod n$ but n is not actually a real prime because $11\times 31=341$.

The author states:

> (In fact, knowing this factorisation in advance, one could 'cheat' in
>   the base 2 test to avoid large computations: since 11 and 31 are
>   primes, Theorem 4.3 gives $2^{10} = 1 \mod (11)$ and $2^{30} = 1 \mod (31)$, 
>   which  easily imply that $2^{341} - 2$ is divisible by both 11 and 31, and
>   hence by 341.)

Was this obvious implication the chinese remainder theorem, or manually plugging one equation into the other, or is there some obvious rule that I don't know about that says $a_1\equiv b \mod n_1$ and $a_2\equiv b \mod n_2$ $\implies$ $a_1a_2\equiv b \mod n_1n_2$

Please don't try to prove the number is pseudoprime, I see an easy implication there ( any a will pass the test mod 11: $a^{10*34+1}\mod 11$, and I can simpify mod 31. I want to know if there's some trick that makes the first two congruences imply the third just but looking at them.

Comment: I think the author made a mistake. If instead we note that $2^5\equiv 1\bmod 31$, then it does indeed follow easily.

Comment: 7= 2 mod 5, and 2=2 mod 13 but 14 != 2 mod 26.  So you don't know that rule for a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $2^5\equiv1\pmod{31}\implies2^{10}=(2^5)^2\equiv1^2=1$

and$2^5\equiv-1\pmod{11}\implies2^{10}\equiv(-1)^2\equiv1$

So, $2^{10}-1$ is divisible by $11,31$ hence by their LCM.

As $n=2^{340}-1=(2^{10})^{34}-1^{34}$ is divisible by $2^{10}-1,2n$ will be divisible by LCM$(11,31)$

Comment: But this follows from $2^5\equiv 1 \bmod 31$, not from $2^{30}\equiv 1 \bmod 31$.

Comment: @TonyK, Exactly,   That's why the Question says: "one could 'cheat'"

Comment: I don't follow you.

Comment: I don't know if this is what the authors had in mind, but this is the way to do it I think. Maybe they made a mistake (I haven't seen many yet in this particular book.)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Because $\;341=31\cdot11\;$ ...and thus

$$2^{341}-2=(2^{31})^{11}-2\ldots$$

Comment: yes but 2 is not a square, so you can't factor out $(2^{31}-1)$

Comment: @use I know $\;2\;$ is not a square (but it is modulo $\;17\;$ , for example...), yet I didn't mean that, but: $$(2^{31})^{11}-2=(2^{31})^{11}-2^{11}=(2^{31}-2)((2^{31})^{10}-2\cdot(2^{31})^{9}+\ldots)$$ i.e. using the development from geometric progressions $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+b^{n-1})$$

Comment: I don't think as fast as some of you answer. I'm still thinking about the other answer...

Comment: @user135711 I didn't say it is "as fast as...". It is a hint, but it doesn't matter: you already got other answers. :)

Comment: Ahhh! Also a good hint/"way to make it easily imply"

Answer (score 1):

$2^{10}\equiv 1 \mod 11$

So $2^{11}\equiv 2 \mod 11$

And $2^{31}\equiv 2 \mod 31$.

So $2^{341}=(2^{11})^{31} \equiv 2^{31} \equiv 2\mod 11$.

So $11|2^{341}-2$.

Likewise for 31.

Comment: This just proves $a \equiv b \mod n_1$ and $a \equiv b \mod n_2$ $\implies a\equiv b \mod n_1 n_2$. I.e. proving that the number is a pseudo-prime manually using the established rules. Although I do appreciate the answer very much. The authors made it seem like when $a_1$ and $a_2$ weren't equal you could multiply them or combine them.

Comment: Um, then I don't understand what your question was.

Comment: Well, as far as I've gotten in this subject, you can only combine primes in the mod base n, when all the a's are equal and all the b's are equal in $a \equiv b \mod n_i$ I was wondering if there was a new rule that I don't know about to combine $a_i\equiv b \mod n_i$ into $a_1a_2\dots\equiv b \mod n_1 n_2\dots$ that I haven't learned yet like it seemed was implied. My question might have been not very well written, but the text so far has been very precise about wording things, so I was thinking there was something I might be missing.

Comment: No, there is no such rule and the author wasn't implying any such rule.  The author was simply say 2^10 = 1 mod 11, and 2^30 =1 mod 31 implies 2^341 - 2 = 0 mod 341.  He concluded that by the reason I gave.  No other.  Your rule is obviously false

Comment: Yes, I didn't think that rule existed. Did you down vote my question?

Comment: No.  I wouldn't do that.